# C# UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, json, utf-8

I have a c# program that retrieve some JSON data and use Newtonsoft JSON to Deserialize it.
as i use persian chars in my program the JSON codes will be shown like this:\u060c \u067e\u0644\u0627\u06a9 .... also after i retrive the JSON data in my program this chars still show like its coded sample.but after i Deserialize it converted to ???? chars.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON deserializer is broken; \uXXXX is supposed to be turned into proper characters.

To do that yourself, use this function

```
// Turns every occurrence of \uXXXX into a proper character
void UnencodeJSONUnicode(string str) {
    return Regex.Replace(str,
                         @"\\u(?<value>[0-9a-f]{4})",
                         match => {
                             string digits = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                             int number = int.Parse(digits, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                             return char.ConvertFromUtf32(number);
                         });
}
```

(Untested code; I don't have VS available at the moment. Some exception handling would probably be nice too)

Comment: @Shiraz: Did you have to make any changes? If so I could incorporate them into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it has been JSON encoded, so you need to decode it. The DataContractJsonSerializer class can do this.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) link for more information.

Comment: `\uXXXX` is not HTML encoding; it's JSON string encoding. HTML encoding looks like `&#XXXX;`.